# Changing the array size

Tags: java, arrays, class

I'm trying to make it so you can change the size of the array with a method.

```
private String[] options;

public static void initOptions(int num)
{
    options = [4]; // this doesn't obviously work
}
```

I could make a new variable

```
private String[] options;

public static void initOptions(int num)
{
    String[] options = new String[num];
}
```

But then I wouldn't be able to share the array with the rest of the class.

Comment: So combine your two choices: options = new STring[num]; (Take off the String[] options = change it to just options = ...)

Comment: @Tristan, is it important for you to work with an instance variable and a static method? because if not then it will very easy

Comment: @Tarik, is it possible to not use anything static?

Comment: @Tristan why not? in my answer you can remove the static keyword from both and it will perfectly work, but the real answer depends on your needs, so i can't tell you if really need to use static or not in your program as i don't have enough informations regarding it

Comment: Once an array is created, you cannot change its size.

Comment: @Tristan please f any answer solved your question consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you also have a mismatch between the static-ness of the `options` field and the `initOptions` function. Usually you'd want them to be the same. That is, you'd want either

```
private String[] options;

public void initOptions(int num)
{
    options = new String[num];
}
```

or

```
private static String[] options;

public static void initOptions(int num)
{
    options = new String[num];
}
```

The first case has one `options` array for each instance of the class, the second has one `options` array shared by all instances of the class.

However, this doesn't really change the **size** of the array.
Once an arrays size is set it cant change. What it does is creates a new array of the desired size and assigns it to your field.

The old value of options will be garbage collected (if nothing else is using it) and none of its old values will be in the new `options` instance. If you want to preserve all the old options you'll need to copy them into the new array. Also anything holding onto the original options field will not see the changes (as they'll keep the old array, not the newly created version)

```
private String[] options;

public void initOptions(int num)
{
    String newOptions = new String[num];
    for(int i=0; i<Math.min(num, options.length); ++i ) {
      newOptions[i] = options[i];
    }
    options = newOptions;
}
```

There are some helper utils that will let you do some of this copying in the core `Arrays` package - but its best to understand what is happening first.

If you want other holders of the options field to see the changes, you can instead use an `ArrayList<String>` to hold your options, as that supports length changes without needing a newly created object.

Comment: I don't know if it's necessary to mention garbage collection. That leads to questions like "How can I make sure these values are garbage collected?" and "Will the JVM garbage collect these objects I still have a reference to?", because the asker thinks they need to do something special to control garbage collection

Comment: Garbage collection is not something special, but it's an essential part of the language. I wanted to say "is destroyed" rather than "will be garbage collected" but really if you're using Java you need to know what garbage collection is (and isn't).

Comment: I would have said "You won't be able to access the old array through `options`" - yes, they will get destroyed eventually if nothing else is using them, but that doesn't affect the correctness of your program. What *does* affect your program is the fact that `options` now refers to something else.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson this will not even compile! you are using an instance variable in a static method, you will have a compiler error: `Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field options`

Comment: @Tarik, ah you're right, only needed change is to either make `options` static, or make `initOptions` non-static. I've tweakes so that is described, and fixed the example code.

Comment: Yep, i know you just forgot it

Answer (score 0):

You are using an instance variable `options` and a `static` method, and it's not possible to mix them (you will end with Compiler error), if you have no real constraints on that, either choose to make the `options` variable static or change the `initOptions` to be `non-static`, thus your code will be very simple:

```
private static String[] options;

public static void initOptions(int num) {
       options = new String[num];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your field options to be assigned the options value your method returns you can write

```
public void initOptions(int num){
    String[] options=new String[num];
    this.options=options;
}
```

and then calling the field f.e from main will call the array.